# How to get key dan value in multidimentional javascript object

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have problem to get output with this JSON

```
{
    status: "ok",
    query:
    {
        format: "JSON",
        city: "667",
        date: "2020-10-14"
    },
    schedule:
    {
        status: "ok",
        data:
        {
            prayer1: "14:46",
            prayer2: "05:55",
            prayer3: "11:42",
            prayer4: "04:06",
            prayer5: "18:58",
            prayer6: "17:48",
            prayer7: "04:16",
            prayer8: "Rabu, 14 Oct 2020",
            prayer9: "05:29"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get specific data key or value (exp. `prayer1`)

I tried this code

```
Object.keys(JSON).forEach(function (key) {
    console.log(JSON[key].data);
});
```

But it just outputs all the data, not a specific data

Comment: you have to iterate json.schedule.data

Comment: If you know what the path is, you can specify it using dot syntax: `var player1data = JSON.schedule.data.player1`.  If you have the key stored in a variable you can combine dot and brackets syntax: `var myPlayerData = JSON.schedule.data[playerName]`.  Beyond, that, I'm not really sure what you are asking.  You'll probably need to provide more information.

Comment: oh myyy .. i  just missed 1 word .. ;) .. 
thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to use a `forEach()` if you want to get a data from a specific key (eg; `prayer1`).

Example;

```js
const data = { status: "ok", query: {format: "JSON", city: "667", date: "2020-10-14"}, schedule: {status: "ok", data: {prayer1: "14:46", prayer2: "05:55", prayer3: "11:42", prayer4: "04:06", prayer5: "18:58", prayer6: "17:48", prayer7: "04:16", prayer8: "Rabu, 14 Oct 2020", prayer9: "05:29"} } }

// To seach
const getKey = 'prayer1';

// Since we only need data.schedule.data
const searchIn = data.schedule.data;

// Get value by key
const value = searchIn[getKey];
console.log(value);
```

Comment: thanks before for your answer.
actually the code output above is the same with
`data.schedule.data.prayer1`

oh myyy .. i'm just miss 1 word .. ;)

Comment: Yes, thats the same idea. I just answered in separated steps so it would be a bit more clear what the steps are.

Answer (score 1):

```
let json = {
   status: "ok",
   query: {
           format: "JSON",
           city: "667",
           date: "2020-10-14"
          },
   schedule: {
            status: "ok",
            data: {
                   prayer1: "14:46",
                   prayer2: "05:55",
                   prayer3: "11:42",
                   prayer4: "04:06",
                   prayer5: "18:58",
                   prayer6: "17:48",
                   prayer7: "04:16",
                   prayer8: "Rabu, 14 Oct 2020",
                   prayer9: "05:29"
                  }
           }
}
Object.keys(json.schedule.data).forEach(key => {
  console.log(json.schedule.data[key])
})

/*
OUTPUT:
14:46
05:55
11:42
04:06
18:58
17:48
04:16
Rabu, 14 Oct 2020
05:29

*/
```

Repl.it:  https://repl.it/join/atkidrbj-theketan2

Comment: by the way .. thanks a lot for your response .. i appreciate it